# how to convert 6 foot 4 inches to meters in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my code, I have to convert 6 foot 4 inches to meter and am getting the incorrect number. Can someone help?

```
var INCHES_TO_CM = 2.54;
var CM_TO_METERS = 0.01;
var FEET_TO_INCHES = 12;

function start(){
    convertHeightToMeters(6,4);
}

function convertHeightToMeters(feet, inches){
    var meters = FEET_TO_INCHES + INCHES_TO_CM * CM_TO_METERS;
    println(meters);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function convertHeightToMeters(feet, inches) {
  return ((feet * FEET_TO_INCHES) + inches) * INCHES_TO_CM * CM_TO_METERS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way for beginners.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id"p1">The conversion</h1>
  <script src="myjsfilename.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The javascript

```
var conversion = function(foot, inch) {
  var inch = inch*2.54;
  var foot = foot*30.48;
  var result = inch + foot;
  result = result/100 + 'm;'
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = result;
};
conversion(6, 4);
```

And an example of how you can turn this into a very simple website (https://conversionfttom.000webhostapp.com/)